# How to find the multiplicative inverse of a polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of the giver irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Find the multiplicative inverse of $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$

$f(x) = x^3-2$
, $\beta = r + s\alpha + t\alpha^{2}$

Attempt:

The gcd of $x^3 - 2$ and $r + sx + tx^2$ is not $1$, so idk what to do.

Comment: Assume $\beta= \frac {1}{\alpha}$ solves some monic cubic polynomial $p(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$.  What happens when you multiply $p(\beta)=0$ through by $\alpha^3$?

Comment: @Robert Shore I'm not following this hint either....

Comment: Meanwhile yes the gcd of $x^3-2$ and $r +sx+tx^2$ is indeed 1 for $r,s,t \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\beta= r+s\alpha+t\alpha^2,$ then $\beta \alpha = r \alpha + s \alpha^2 + t \alpha^3= 2t+r \alpha + s \alpha^2$ and $\beta \alpha^2 = 2t \alpha + r \alpha^2 + s \alpha^3= 2s+ 2t \alpha + r \alpha^2$.  Thus, $$\beta(a+b \alpha + c \alpha^2)=(ar+as\alpha+ at\alpha^2)+(2bt+br\alpha + bs\alpha^2)+(2cs+2ct\alpha+cr\alpha^2)\\=(ar+2bt+2cs)+(as+br+2ct)\alpha+(at+bs+cr)\alpha^2=1+ 0 \alpha + 0 \alpha^2.$$

Equating coefficients of powers of $\alpha$ (and remembering that $r, s, t$ are given) gives you three equations for the unknowns $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many, many ways of doing this. Let me show you one that is good for the relatively simple polynomial $X^3-2$.

For quadratic polynomials, it’s easy: you multiply the expression $a+b\sqrt m$ by its conjugate $a-b\sqrt m$, and get a rational number $a^2-mb^2$, which allows you to write the reciprocal: $$\frac1{a+b\sqrt m}=\frac{a-b\sqrt m}{a^2-mb^2}\,.$$
For your $r+s\alpha+t\alpha^2$, you do the same thing, using the primitive cube root of  unity $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$and the fact that $\alpha$ has *two* conjugates, namely $\omega\alpha$ and $\omega^2\alpha$. They are conjugates of $\alpha$ because they equally are roots of $X^3-2$. You multiply,
$$
(r+s\alpha+t\alpha^2)(r+s\omega\alpha+t\omega^2\alpha^2)(r+s\omega^2\alpha+t\omega\alpha^2)
$$
You really must do the computation out yourself, using the minimal relation for $\omega$, which is $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. But I’ll destroy the suspense and tell you that you get $r^3+2s^3+4t^3-6rst$. This is called the Norm of $r+s\alpha+t\alpha^2$. You’ll notice that it’s in $\Bbb Q$, and that allows you to write out the reciprocal of $r+s\alpha+t\alpha^2$

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a polynomial $\gamma(\alpha)$ so that the following (D) is satisfied:

$$qf(\alpha) + \gamma\beta(\alpha) = 1$$ for some polynomial $q_1$. Then $\gamma(\alpha)$ and $\beta(\alpha)$ are multiplicative inverses.

Now write divide $f$ by $\beta$ to get

$$f = g_1\beta + r_1,$$ or equivalently, (A):

$$r_1 = g_1\beta - f,$$ where $g_1,r \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$; deg$(r) < $deg$(\beta)$.

[Can you find $g_1$ and $r_1$?] Note that here $r_1$ has degree 1. In turn, divide $f$ by $r_1$ to get (B):

$$f = g_2r_1 - a_0$$ where $g_2 \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$; $a_0 \in \mathbb{Q}; a_0 \not = 0$; I trust that you can find $g_2$ and $a_0$ as well.

Plugging (A) into (B) gives

$$f = g_2(g_1\beta - f) - a_0$$, or equivalently,

$$a_0+ f + g_2f = g_2g_1\beta; \ a_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$$

Compare this to (D). an you finish from here.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Or for that matter, the question itself

Comment: So the solution should be $\frac{g_{1}(\alpha)g_{2}(\alpha)}{a_0}$, right? Since $deg(g_1)=1$ and $deg(g_2)=2$, it should have a degree of 3. But the answer that's given in the book doesn't have an $\alpha^{3}$ term

Comment: @Daniel Lin keep in mind that you need to use the relation $\alpha^3-2=0$ or $\alpha^3=2$, to get a polynomial of degree 2 or less

Comment: Actually, I can't even divide $g_1(\alpha)g_2(\alpha)$ by $a_0$ because it has a degree greater than 0.

Comment: $a_0$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ and is nonzero; dividing by $a _0$ is multiplying by $\frac{1}{a_0}$.